# Responsive slick Slider

Tags: css, responsive-design, slider, slick.js

i create this slick slider.
Someone could help me to fix the responsive breadcrumbs?

slick-content-slider slick-initialized slick-slider take a strange height ...
What i want to create is that every div remain on the same line .
Thank You in advance !

```js
$('.slick-content-slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  arrows: true
});
```

```css
.slick-content-slider {
  margin: 0 2.5%;
  width: 95%;
}

.content-slide {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}

@charset "UTF-8";
/* Slider */
.slick-slider { position: relative; display: block; box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; -ms-touch-action: pan-y; touch-action: pan-y; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; }

.slick-list { position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.slick-list:focus { outline: none; }
.slick-loading .slick-list { background: #fff url("./ajax-loader.gif") center center no-repeat; }
.slick-list.dragging { cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; }

.slick-slider .slick-track { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); }

.slick-track { position: relative; left: 0; top: 0; display: block; }
.slick-track:before, .slick-track:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.slick-track:after { clear: both; }
.slick-loading .slick-track { visibility: hidden; }

.slick-slide { float: left; height: 100%; min-height: 1px; display: none; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-slide { float: right; }
.slick-slide img { display: block; }
.slick-slide.slick-loading img { display: none; }
.slick-slide.dragging img { pointer-events: none; }
.slick-initialized .slick-slide { display: block; }
.slick-loading .slick-slide { visibility: hidden; }
.slick-vertical .slick-slide { display: block; height: auto; border: 1px solid transparent; }

/* Icons */
@font-face { font-family: "slick"; src: url("./fonts/slick.eot"); src: url("./fonts/slick.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("./fonts/slick.woff") format("woff"), url("./fonts/slick.ttf") format("truetype"), url("./fonts/slick.svg#slick") format("svg"); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
/* Arrows */
.slick-prev, .slick-next { position: absolute; display: block; height: 20px; width: 20px; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; cursor: pointer; background: transparent; color: transparent; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px; padding: 0; border: none; outline: none; }
.slick-prev:hover, .slick-prev:focus, .slick-next:hover, .slick-next:focus { outline: none; background: transparent; color: transparent; }
.slick-prev:hover:before, .slick-prev:focus:before, .slick-next:hover:before, .slick-next:focus:before { opacity: 1; }
.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before, .slick-next.slick-disabled:before { opacity: 0.25; }

.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before { font-family: "slick"; font-size: 20px; line-height: 1; color: white; opacity: 0.75; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }

.slick-prev { left: -25px; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev { left: auto; right: -25px; }
.slick-prev:before { content: "←"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev:before { content: "→"; }

.slick-next { right: -25px; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-next { left: -25px; right: auto; }
.slick-next:before { content: "→"; }
[dir="rtl"] .slick-next:before { content: "←"; }

/* Dots */
.slick-slider { margin-bottom: 30px; }

.slick-dots { position: absolute; bottom: -45px; list-style: none; display: block; text-align: center; padding: 0; width: 100%; }
.slick-dots li { position: relative; display: inline-block; height: 20px; width: 20px; margin: 0 5px; padding: 0; cursor: pointer; }
.slick-dots li button { border: 0; background: transparent; display: block; height: 20px; width: 20px; outline: none; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; color: transparent; padding: 5px; cursor: pointer; }
.slick-dots li button:hover, .slick-dots li button:focus { outline: none; }
.slick-dots li button:hover:before, .slick-dots li button:focus:before { opacity: 1; }
.slick-dots li button:before { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; content: "•"; width: 20px; height: 20px; font-family: "slick"; font-size: 6px; line-height: 20px; text-align: center; color: black; opacity: 0.25; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; }
.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before { color: black; opacity: 0.75; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=slick.css.map */
```

```html
 <body>

    <div class="slick-content-slider">
  <div class="content-slide">slide 1</div>
  <div class="content-slide">slide 2</div>
  <div class="content-slide">slide 3</div>
  <div class="content-slide">slide 4</div>
  <div class="content-slide">slide 5</div>
  <div class="content-slide">slide 6</div>
</div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.3.15/slick.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    
    
    
  </body>
```

Comment: The code you posted appears to be working the way you want it to. I'm looking at it in Firefox, is the error happening in a specific browser?

Comment: yes on safari it seems don't work, foolishly i don't check on other browser..

Comment: But also on chrome it don't work, div line up on 3 column, what i try to do is to align it only on one column when browser window narrows

Comment: i try to insert on css class .slick-track::before, .slick-track::after the value display : inline-table, it seems works better... any suggestion ?! thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think I've solved, i add this at class ".slick-content-slider" :

```
    .slick-content-slider {

  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height:250px;
}
```